# How to trigger facebook Dialog with a list of friends

Tags: objective-c, ios, facebook, dialog

Is there a way to trigger a facebook dialog with list of friends in the iPhone client?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this as shown in [iOS Tutorial (Step 7: Integrating with Social Channels)](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/ios/build/#socialchannels)

```
NSMutableDictionary* params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                           @"Come check out my app.",  @"message",
                           nil];

[facebook dialog:@"apprequests"
              andParams:params
            andDelegate:self];
```

**Update:**
If you want those requests will be visible to users on Facebook (not just in your application), than you need to provide **Site URL** or **Canvas URL** in application settings (this will be the URL user redirected on request accept). Otherwise those requests will only be accessible by API, so you'll be able to get 'em within application and show to users.

Comment: Oh, I don't have to pass in the list of friends in this case?

Comment: You can pass it as comma-separated list of user ids in `to` parameter of Requests Dialog, but you not required to... If you skip this you'll see all user's friends, if you pass it, only users from passed list will be displayed...

Comment: I managed to see the dialog, but the targets did not receive the notifications after I sent. Is there anyway to check what went wrong?

Comment: Hi, but I do have a URL defined in the app settings. Just that it is for localhost. Is that an issue?

Comment: Do you have `localhost` in **App Domain** too?

Comment: Oh, there is an opened bug on subject (you can track it here [Bug #189105344504911](http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/189105344504911)), looks like this is the reason requests not shown...

Comment: Oh bummer. Thanks for your help on this. Hopefully this gets resolved soon. I see that it is opened since november

Answer (score 0):

The answer from the iOS Tutorial works fine for me, except it does not show friends to choose from.  If I type a letter, then it shows me friends whose name starts with that, but I cannot figure out how to see the entire friends list to choose from, as the question asked.

Comment: This is not an answer, please move to comment as appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [FBWebDialogs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/3.2/class/FBWebDialogs)
which is part of FacebookSDK.

For Example, if the session is already active, try this:

```
[FBWebDialogs presentRequestsDialogModallyWithSession:nil message:@"Message" title:nil parameters:nil handler:nil];
```